# Vector space of elementary abelian group

Tags: linear-algebra

Say we are considering $$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$$

So it seems that under standard operations mod $2$, this forms a vector space.

It is clear that it has four elements ie, $\{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$

But my question is basic, it is about finding all the subspaces and being able to conclude that I have found all that exist.

My thoughts;

Any subspace must contain $\{(0,0)\}$

We have the two trivial subspaces, the space itself and just the zero vector.

Then, it seems that there exist five subspaces, we could form things such as 
$$\{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$$
$$\{(0,0),(1,0)\}$$
$$\{(0,0),(0,1)\}$$
$$\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$$
$$\{(0,0)\}$$
It seems like that would be it, because we need to assure that we stay closed under addition. But I am not sure. Are there other subspaces? and how would I prove that no other exist?

Thanks

Comment: That's all of them. (Aside: When you assert a set is a vector space, you need to state the field over which it is a vector space.)

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to prove that no other exist? and okay, it is the field with two element

Comment: Sure, just show that if two of $\{(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$ are in a sub-space, then so is the third.

Answer (score 1):

This space is a 2-dim linear space over the field Z/2Z (as a sum of two 1-dim spaces). So any proper subspace must have dim = 1. Your list contains all 1-dim subspaces, the space itself and zero space. Right answer.